# Newly installed 3/4 ball valve is slightly leaking between the stem and nut

Tags: leak, valve

A 3/4 ball valve just installed in the basement of a 2 storey house is leaking about 1 drop of water a min where the arrow in the picture is pointing. Is the seal going to swell, of will the valve have to be replaced?

The valve is Watts, from Home Depot. It was soldered with lead free solder. It shuts off water with no leaks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tightening the nuts did not stop the leaks, but after a couple days the leak stopped all by itself.

Answer (score 4):

You could try tightening the packing nut (just about where your leak is - the one under the handle - probably easier with the handle off.)

Very unlikely that the packing will swell, as it's typically teflon or similar plastic.